# How can I fill the region from the minimum value of all curves to the x axis

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, filling

How can I fill the region from the minimum value of all curves to the x axis like this?

```
myfunctions = {ConditionalExpression[1 + x^2, x >= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x >= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1, x > 3], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 - x^3/33, x <= 0]};
Plot[myfunctions, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

It is kind of reverse of `Filling->Top` but not `Filling->Bot`.

[image: ?]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
minF = Min[Block[{Undefined = 10^5}, #]] &;

filling = Plot[minF @ myfunctions, {x, -5, 5}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
   PlotStyle -> None, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5, Yellow]];

Show[filling, Plot[myfunctions, {x, -5, 5}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define

```
myfunctions2 := Append[minF @ myfunctions] @ myfunctions
```

and use a single `Plot` with `None` as the plot style for the last function in the list:

```
Plot[myfunctions2, {x, -5, 5}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Append[None] @ ConstantArray[Automatic, 4], 
 Filling -> {5 -> Axis}, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5, Yellow]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

We note that the yellow part is the complement of the `Filling->Top`, so we use `RegionDifference`.

```
myfunctions = {ConditionalExpression[1 + x^2, x >= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x >= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1, x > 3], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 - x^3/33, x <= 0]};
plot = Plot[myfunctions, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}},
    GridLines -> Automatic];
reg = Plot[myfunctions, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, Filling -> Top] // DiscretizeGraphics;
reg1 = Graphics[{Opacity[.2], Yellow, 
    DiscretizeRegion[
     RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-5, 0}, {5, 5}], reg]]}];
Show[plot, reg1]
```

[image]